# Problems updating array(?)

Tags: c++

Am trying to create an inventory system for a text based adventuer game we gotta make for an assignment but am having a trouble with my item array.

When i try to change/update an item in the array it 'updates' but when i loop though it with a command after wards its not updated

the edit method prints corrently

Would appriciate some help

```
void Inventory::edit(int slot, Item item)
{
    cout << "changing slot: " << slot << endl;
    cout << "old Id: " << this->items[slot].getId() << endl;
    this->items[slot] = item;
    cout << "new Id: " << this->items[slot].getId() << endl;
}

changing slot: 0
old Id: -1
new Id: 1

void Inventory::printInventory()
{
    cout << "Your inventory:" << endl;
    for (Item item : this->items) {
        cout << "id: " << item.getId() << endl;
    }
}

prints
Your inventory:
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
id: -1
```

***Inventory.h***

```
#pragma once
#include "Item.h"

using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
private:
public:
    Inventory();
    ~Inventory();
    Item items[28];
    void clear();
    void edit(int slot, Item item);
    void add(Item item);
    void add(Item item, int slot);
    void remove(Item item);
    bool contains(string name);
    int getNextFreeSlot();
    int getSlot(int itemId);
    int freeSlots();
    void printInventory();
};
```

***Item.h***

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Item
{
private:
    int id;
    int amount;
    bool stackable;
public:
    //Used for setting the amount of the item
    void setAmount(int amount);
    //Used for grabbing the amount of the item
    int getAmount();
    //Sets the item id
    void setId(int id);
    //Grabs the item id
    int getId();
    Item();
    ~Item();
    //Used for generating an item with just an id, will automaticlly set the amount to 1
    Item(int id);
    //Used for generating an iteem with an id and an set amount
    Item(int id, int amount);
    //Gets the name of an item
    string getName();
    //Gets if an item is stackable
    bool isStackable();
};
```

Comment: How is `Inventory` defined? What is `items`? What is `Item`? How is `edit` invoked? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: in the function it is using copies (passed by value) try to add reference :
void Inventory::edit(int slot, Item& item)

Comment: @SergeyA But I fail to see where `item` is modified.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Its defined in my player class like this:
Inventory inventory; and items is an array of my Item class Item items[28]; in my Inventory.h

Comment: @NighelNijhuis Sure.. My point was: we cannot see it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius oh! You are correct.

Comment: I added the 2 .h files from inventory and item.

Comment: @NighelNijhuis I asked for [mcve]. Your example is still not complete (we cannot copy-paste it, run it, and reproduce the same problem). Note: I am not asking for full code. I am asking for manufactured [mcve].

Comment: @NighelNijhuis : add the class definition for functions using the item.

Comment: Minor point: I think that in every case where you've written `this->` you can remove it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i dont mind sharing the whole thing its nothing special https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsmxebfxme5jbap/Adventure%20Project.zip?dl=0

Comment: @NighelNijhuis 1) The information necessary to answer question must be in the question itself, and not hidden behind external links. 2) Once again, I didn't ask for full code. Please [edit] your question with [mcve].

Comment: @NighelNijhuis : and what are the commands to use.. add ?? test?? how reproduce it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the Player class, you have to return by Reference.

make modifications :

***Player.cpp***

```
Inventory& Player::getInventory()
{
    return this->inventory;
}
```

***Player.h***

```
Inventory& getInventory();
```

Comment: Thank  you very much that was indeed the problem. am gonna read a bit more about reference.